# Mocking in Laravel with GitHub API Wrapper?

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, laravel-6, mockery

I'm new to Mockery. I'm trying to figure it out with the GitHub API by using a Laravel Package as a wrapper. How can I mock `GitHub::repo()->show('symfony', 'demo');` without hiting the actual API? Is there something weird with Facades? I'm getting an error here:

```
In EvalLoader.php(34) : eval()'d code line 993:

  Cannot redeclare Mockery_0_GrahamCampbell_GitHub_Facades_GitHub::shouldReceive()
```

Code:

```
    use Mockery;
    use Tests\TestCase;
    use GrahamCampbell\GitHub\Facades\GitHub;



    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->mockGitHubWith([
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'demo',
            'full_name' => 'symfony/demo',
        ]);

        $repo = GitHub::repo()->show('symfony', 'demo');

        dd($repo);
    }

    protected function mockGitHubWith($expectations)
    {
        $github = Mockery::mock(GitHub::class, $expectations);
        $github->shouldReceive('api')->andReturn($github);
        app()->instance(GitHub::class, $github);
    }
```

also tried:

```
use GrahamCampbell\GitHub\Facades\GitHub;

public function testExample()
    {
        Github::shouldReceive('api')->once()->andReturn(['id' => 1]);

        $repo = Github::repo()->show('symfony', 'demo');

        dd($repo);
    }
```

Returns: `Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_0::repo() does not exist on this mock object`

Just to confirm, if I remove the `GitHub::shouldReceive...`  line, it's successful but actually hits the GitHub API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the last example you are almost there. Remember you are trying to mock a two step call, first a static method and a call to an instance, therefor the mock should emulate that.

Create the repository that the `repo()` call will return. Using standard mockery functionality.

```
use Github\Api\Repo;

$repoMock = Mockery::mock(Repo::class);
$repoMock->shouldReceive('show')->with('symfony', 'demo')->once()->andReturn(['id' => 1]);
```

Now you can set the return type of the repo call through `Laravels` approach to mock facades.

```
Github::shouldReceive('repo')->once()->andReturn($repoMock);
```

When you call your code repo will return the repo mock, that expects a show call with the parameters `symfony` and `demo`.

```
$repo = Github::repo()->show('symfony', 'demo');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been looking for an answer that explains this for a week.. greatly appreciated.

Comment: Feel free to ping me here if you have more questions have done a lot of mocking of weird stuff :)

Comment: Thanks! I have another weird edge case-- feel free to help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60342730/laravel-how-to-mock-dependency-injection-class-methods